# Returning a boolean if an element occurs more than three times in an array

Tags: ruby

I need to take an array and return `true` if it contains an element three times or more. If the array contains an element that occurs less than three times, it needs to return `false`. I am guessing I need to use the `count` method, but I am stuck as to what to put in my block. I have written the following code:

```
def got_three?(array)
  array.count {|x|}
end

got_three? ([1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7])
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: What should it return when the array contains both an element that occurs three times and an element that occurs less than three times?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `#count`, but you'll also need another primitive, since you want to check for each element. In this case, `#any?` will suffice.

```
def got_three?(array)
  array.any? { |y| array.count(y) >= 3 }
end
```

This returns whether any element which appears in the array appears at least three times.

Comment: Although this would work, you're iterating the array at least once **for every object before the triple object** ... If the triple object is the third, you're iterating the array three times... this seems a somewhat wasteful solution. Had I been by my laptop, I'd offer more input.

Comment: It is true that this approach operates in quadratic time where a more efficient algorithm could do the same in linear time, but what this approach forfeits in time it gains in space (no extra storage needed) as well as elegance (this is much clearer than the code you would have to write to get linear time), so unless you're regularly dealing with arrays in the neighborhood of thousands of elements, I would argue that the more readable approach is better.

Comment: `array.each_with_object({}) {|i,h| h[i] = h[i].to_i + 1; return true if h[i] >= 3}; false;` this would iterate once (or less)...

Comment: @Myst Post that as a second answer then. Then anyone who looks at this question can choose which approach is best for their purposes.

Comment: Since ruby is often used to write server applications, I would argue that speed related performance is very important. At the least, the answer should point out performance issues... We don't want people to forget that Ruby can be fast.

Comment: @Myst, I hadn't seen `h[i].to_i + 1` before. I like it!

Comment: @CarySwoveland But that is with the cost of not being able to use `+=`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, @sawa,  right.. I wrote the comment on my iPhone, so it was a dirty hash for `nil.to_i`... later I updated it to `Hash.new(0)` in my answer. Should be easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

Although I love Silvio's answer, it does, potentially, iterate over the array multiple times.

Depending on the array's size and how often this method is used, it could hurt performance - especially if used for a server application, such as within Rails.

The following might be less readable, but should perform better:

```
def has_three?(array)
   h = (Thread.current[:_has_three_buffer] ||= Hash.new(0)).clear
   array.each do |i|
      h[i] += 1
      return true if h[i] >= 3
   end
   false
end
```

#### Edit

A quick explanation about the optimizations in the method.

1. **Speed:**

   The method uses a Hash to map how many times each element is repeated. This allows for less iterations.

   The method iterates over the array no more then once, stopping the moment a `true` response is available.

   This method would read, at the very least 3 elements from the array. At the most, this method will iterate once through the array.
2. **Memory and object allocation (overhead):**

   Creating a Hash to map the array is an expensive overhead that can (and should) be minimized.

   The overhead is cause by the performance price related to the object creation and initialization (including the initial memory allocation).

   Benchmarking shows that the overhead is well worth the price when the triple object is deeper within the array (i.e., located after the third position).

   This method created a single Hash per thread, that will be used whenever the method is called. This is a better approach than using a Mutex which might provide thread safety but prevent parallel concurrency (i.e., when using JRuby).

   The Hash is stored in the current thread using `Thread.current`'s memory store.

   The Hash: `Thread.current[:_has_three_buffer] ||= Hash.new(0)` will remain in the thread's memory until the thread exits, so that main bulk of the overhead is avoided and replaced with the smaller overhead of accessing the Hash and "clearing" the it's memory using `clear`.

   The `Hash.new(0)` means that hash will return `0` instead of `nil` for missing elements.

#### Updated Benchmarks

Benchmarking the different solutions surprised me in a positive way. Silvio's solution wasn't as slow as I feared and Jon's solution was slower than I thought...

I was also amazed by the memory used by the solutions. My approach used more memory than I thought, but it was still optimized when compared to Wand's approach

Here are the measurements for 100,000 iterations using some sample Arrays.

The first two benchmarks are a 10 items long array with the triplet (the object occurring three times) in either the beginning (where my answer is at a disadvantage due to it's overhead) or the end (where some answers are at a disadvantage due to iterations).

> -- **Array (10 items): [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]**
>
> **silvio  0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.043519)**
>
> myst  0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.074734)
>
> jon  0.240000   0.010000   0.250000 (  0.252569)
>
> wand  0.260000   0.030000   0.290000 (  0.289101)
>
> -- **Array (10 items): [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]**
>
> silvio  0.310000   0.000000   0.310000 (  0.313565)
>
> **myst  0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.298405)**
>
> jon  0.530000   0.010000   0.540000 (  0.534697)
>
> wand  0.310000   0.030000   0.340000 (  0.350704)

Next I measured a 10 items long array with the triplet at the approximate middle (starting on item number 5).

I also reviewed approximate memory usage for the 10 item long array review for 100K iterations. The memory review includes the memory used to benchmark and build the report and it isn't accurate in any way... but it probably shows something...

> -- **Array (10 items): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 8, 9, 10]**
>
> Memory used (by printing the Array): 4KB - showing this isn't accurate
>
> **silvio  0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.200012)**
>
> Memory used (silvio): **4KB**
>
> myst  0.210000   0.010000   0.220000 (  0.214936)
>
> Memory used (myst): 5,944KB
>
> jon  0.420000   0.000000   0.420000 (  0.422354)
>
> Memory used (jon): 18,364KB
>
> wand  0.300000   0.030000   0.330000 (  0.342656)
>
> Memory used (wand): **118,496KB** (~118MB!)

As you can see, when reviewing short arrays (10 items), the differences are very small and might not be worth the memory used for optimizing the method for longer arrays.

Next I did the same (triplet in the middle) with a 50 items long array... this was when the difference in iterations really showed up. i.e., while my answer used ~1.5 seconds, Silvio's approach took ~7.5 seconds - about 5 times slower.

> -- **Array (50 items): [1...47, 50, 50, 50]**
>
> silvio  7.560000   0.010000   7.570000 (  7.570565)
>
> **myst  1.480000   0.010000   1.490000 (  1.487640)**
>
> jon  8.290000   0.020000   8.310000 (  8.316714)
>
> wand  1.550000   0.150000   1.700000 (  1.700455)

However, Jon pointed out that the benchmarks were very sterile, with no duplicate objects except the triplet, so next I benchmarked an array with 100 items, where each item was duplicated twice (except the triplet). The triplet was in the middle.

This is where Jon's overhead (using `unique`) shows it's advantage. While Jon's approach took ~8.6 seconds, Silvio's approach climbed to ~14 seconds. Both Wand and I remained in the single digits, with my answer being the fastest - ~1.2 seconds.

I also reviewed the approximate memory growth caused by both the iterations and the Benchmarking itself...

Some of the solutions used a LOT of memory. i.e., Wand's beautiful solution built up to ~0.5GB(!) for the 100 items long array (100K iterations), while Jon's solution used ~50MB, my solution built up to ~5MB and Silvio's solution seems to have used no memory at all (which is probably a glitch that shows how inaccurate the memory testing is).

Again, memory usage isn't accurate.

> -- **Array (100 items): [1..23,1..23,24, 25,25,25, 26..50,26..50]**
>
> Memory used (by printing the Array): 4KB - showing this isn't accurate
>
> silvio 14.090000   0.010000  14.100000 ( 14.100915)
>
> Memory used (silvio): **0KB**
>
> **myst  1.170000   0.010000   1.180000 (  1.182665)**
>
> Memory used (myst): 5,992KB
>
> jon  8.570000   0.020000   8.590000 (  8.592982)
>
> Memory used (jon): 51720KB
>
> wand  1.940000   0.160000   2.100000 (  2.093121)
>
> Memory used (wand): **569,264KB** (~569MB!)

Code for benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'

def silvio_got_three?(array)
  array.any? { |y| array.count(y) >= 3 }
end

def myst_has_three?(array)
   h = (Thread.current[:_has_three_buffer] ||= Hash.new(0)).clear
   # h = Hash.new(0)
   array.each do |i|
      h[i] += 1
      return true if h[i] >= 3
   end
   false
end

def jon_has_three?(array)
  array.uniq.any? { |x| array.count(x) >= 3 }
end

def wand_has_three?(array)
  array.group_by {|i| i }.any? {|_, v| v.size >= 3}
end

def get_total_memory_used
  `ps -o rss= -p #{Process.pid}`.to_i
end

# warm-up
myst_has_three? [0]

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  a = [1,1,1] + (2..8).to_a
  repeat = 100_000
  GC.disable
  puts "Array (#{a.length} items): #{a.to_s}"
  bm.report('silvio') { repeat.times { silvio_got_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('myst') { repeat.times { myst_has_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('jon') { repeat.times { jon_has_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('wand') { repeat.times { wand_has_three?(a) } }
  a.reverse!
  puts "Array (#{a.length} items): #{a.to_s}"
  bm.report('silvio') { repeat.times { silvio_got_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('myst') { repeat.times { myst_has_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('jon') { repeat.times { jon_has_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('wand') { repeat.times { wand_has_three?(a) } }
  a = (1..4).to_a + [5,5,5] + (8..10).to_a
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  puts "Array (#{a.length} items): #{a.to_s}"
  puts "Memory used (by printing the Array): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB - showing this isn't accurate"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  bm.report('silvio') { repeat.times { silvio_got_three?(a) } }
  puts "Memory used (silvio): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  bm.report('myst') { repeat.times { myst_has_three?(a) } }
  puts "Memory used (myst): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  bm.report('jon') { repeat.times { jon_has_three?(a) } }
  puts "Memory used (jon): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  bm.report('wand') { repeat.times { wand_has_three?(a) } }
  puts "Memory used (wand): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB"
  mem = get_total_memory_used 
  a = (1..47).to_a + [50,50,50]
  puts "Array (#{a.length} items): #{a.to_s}"
  bm.report('silvio') { repeat.times { silvio_got_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('myst') { repeat.times { myst_has_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('jon') { repeat.times { jon_has_three?(a) } }
  bm.report('wand') { repeat.times { wand_has_three?(a) } }
  a = (1..23).to_a*2 + [24,25,25,25] + (26..50).to_a*2
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  puts "Array (#{a.length} items): [1..23,1..23,24, 25,25,25, 26..50,26..50]"
  puts "Memory used (by printing the Array): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB - showing this isn't accurate"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  bm.report('silvio') { repeat.times { silvio_got_three?(a) } }
  puts "Memory used (silvio): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  bm.report('myst') { repeat.times { myst_has_three?(a) } }
  puts "Memory used (myst): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  bm.report('jon') { repeat.times { jon_has_three?(a) } }
  puts "Memory used (jon): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  bm.report('wand') { repeat.times { wand_has_three?(a) } }
  puts "Memory used (wand): #{get_total_memory_used - mem}KB"
  mem = get_total_memory_used
  GC.start
end; nil
```

Comment: Why use `Thread.current[]`? I assume this is a performance optimization, but could you elaborate on it?

Comment: @DanielStevens - I edited the answer to include some explanations... essentially it prevents the method from creating new Hash objects whenever it's called, keeping a single Hash in the memory as a recyclable buffer. Storing the Hash in the thread's memory store allows the method to be thread-safe without using a Mutex for the buffer and without disruption to concurrent method calls.

Comment: The array in your benchmark brought a smile to my face, not the `2`'s piled up near the front, but the `1` that precedes them. It's as though you couldn't bring yourself to put the three `2`'s at the *very* front. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Ha :) I didn't notice that one, I just copied the array from the question. It is funny, though. I wonder how much effect it could have on the benchmark.

Comment: Nice. Can I ask about benchmarking with and without the Thread.current part?

Comment: @DanielStevens creating a new Hash object for every method call would slow the method by ~25% (on my machine) due to object creation and memory allocations. This is just speed. The real issue might be memory over time (array size dependent). Using the same benchmarks, the difference on my machine was about 15Mb used for the new Hash objects...

Comment: Couldn't the whole Thread thing be avoided by, say, making this a module method with a `@_has_three_buffer` variable?

Comment: @Jordan - if you do that, than the module wouldn't be thread-safe. Think of two threads using the module at the same time and accessing the `@_has_three_buffer` at the same time... This is exactly the situation that the `Thread.current[:key]` attempts to avoid. A module would need to store the buffer in a thread-safe storage rather than as a global variable.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Jordan - my pleasure :) it's a very commonly ignored and important issue. I'm happy you asked.

Comment: @Myst When the thread gets re-used second time, wouldn't hash still have the values from previous computation? That to me sounds like thread safety issue

Comment: @Myst - Good call on benchmarking these. I've added an additional benchmark test to show what happens when the array has lots of duplicate non-matching items. I think it's good to show how in some instances the `uniq` can play an important role. However, when you consider that each call to `count` will iterate over the entire array it's easy to see how your solution will be far more performant. Nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

Silvio's answer will work, but as Myst pointed out, it will iterate over the array multiple times with the same arguments.

This should be a little better, without the complexity of Myst's solution:

```
def has_three?(array)
  array.uniq.any? { |x| array.count(x) >= 3 }
end
```

This slight difference means that you will only iterate over the array once for each unique element, rather than running an additional check for every duplicate element.

Comment: Interesting. A quick google shows that `Array#uniq` actually does all of Myst's hash stuff internally and operates in linear time itself, so this really is a great middle ground between the two answers.

Comment: @Jon I loved the simplicity. However, benchmarks show that this is actually slower than Silvio's answer. I assume that this is because the `unique` doesn't really help when using the array in the example (since it doesn't include repeated elements that appear before the triple `2`)... perhaps the overhead for `unique` isn't worth the reward for most common uses...?

Comment: @Myst the real downside to both mine and Silvio's solutions is that `Array.count` iterates over the entire array. So even with only checking the unique elements your hash based solution will be faster with it's single iteration over the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this as well:

```
[1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7].group_by {|i| i }.any? {|_, v| v.size >= 3}
```

Comment: Yup, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: I loved the simplicity and the approach to minimizing iteration... but although it might be a faster solution then some, it would be a memory hog (still, a very beautiful memory hog)... I'll add it to the Benchmarking.